# Idempotent and similar matrix using Einstein notation

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

> 1. Write the idempotency condition in indices with Einstein summation
> 2. Write the similarity condition in indices, as the vanishing of each $(i,j)$th coefficient of the difference $AP-PB$

1. let $A=a^{i}_{j}$ and let's look at $$a^{i}_{j}a^{i}_{j}=a^{i}_{j}\iff a^{i}_{j}=\delta_{i}^{i}$$ which is just one case of a matrix being idempotent
2. $$a^{i}_{j}p^{j}_{k}-b^{n}_{l}p^{l}_{m}=0$$
   Next step can be written as $$a^{i}p_{k}-b^{n}p_{m}=0$$

But what then?

Comment: A matrix $A$ is idempotent if $A^2 = A$, but I don't see how $a^i_j a^i_j$ represents $A^2$: if anything that looks more like an elementwise squaring.

Comment: @ErickWong Doesn't $A^2=(a^{i}_{j})^2=a^{i}_{j}a^{i}_{j}$?

Comment: No, you don't square a matrix by squaring each individual element.  Would you write $a^i_j b^i_j$ for the matrix product $AB$?

Comment: @ErickWong I am new at this but isnt it like $AB=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}b_{kj}$? or wait a second the problem is that it should be $a^{i}_{k}a^{k}_{j}$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  The summation convention allows you to omit the $\sigma_k$ when the $k$-indices line up, but $a^i_j a^i_j$ is a bit nonsensical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the matrix product in Einstein summation is understood, one can esily formulate an answer to both the questions (1) and (2).

The matrix product is defined with upper and lower ($i=$ row, $j=$ column) indices as:
$$
A B = \left[ (AB)^i_j \right] = \left[ \sum_k A^i_k B^k_j \right]
$$
With the Einstein convention, the summation $\sum_k$ is replaced by the assumption that summation is automatically
over upper and lower indices *iff they are the same*. Hence:
$$
(AB)^i_j = A^i_k B^k_j
$$
Now idempotency (1) can be formulated as:
$$
A^2 = A \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad (AA)^i_j = A^i_k A^k_j = A^i_j
$$
And similarity (2) can be formulated as:
$$
AP=PB \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad (AP)^i_j = A^i_k P^k_j = P^i_k B^k_j = (PB)^i_j
$$
Or should I say : $\;A^i_k P^k_j - P^i_k B^k_j = 0$ ?